# $a_i$ are the n-th roots of $1\in\mathbb{C}$, why does $(1-a_2)\cdot...\cdot(1-a_n)=n$?

Tags: complex-numbers, roots-of-unity

For $1<i\leq n$, let $a_i$ be the  n-th roots of $1\in\mathbb{C}$, why does $(1-a_2)\cdot...\cdot(1-a_n)=n$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3038472/if-x-1-x-2-ldots-x-n-are-the-roots-for-1xx2-ldotsxn-0-find-the-value/3038481#3038481

Comment: You can use the derivative of $x^n-1$ to show the slightly more general rule that 
 for any $j-1,2,\dots,n:$ $$na_j^{-1}=\prod_{i\neq j} (a_j-a_i).$$

Answer (score 5):

$$z^n - 1 = (z-1)(z^{n-1} + \cdots + z + 1) = (z-1)\prod_{i=2}^n(z-a_i)$$

$$\Rightarrow z^{n-1} + \cdots + z + 1 = \prod_{i=2}^n(z-a_i) \stackrel{z=1}{\Rightarrow} n = \prod_{i=2}^n(1-a_i)$$

Comment: In the first equation in the second $=$ sign, why does $z^{n-1}+...+z+1=(z-a_2)\cdot\dots\cdot (z-a_n)$?

Comment: @J.Doe : The equality in the first line holds because of the fundamental theorem of algebra: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra . The second line follows for $z \neq 1$. But as we have polynomials on both sides which are equal for all $z \neq 1$, then they are also equal for $z = 1$. (Note that two polynomials of degree $m$ are identical iff they are equal at $m+1$ points $z_0, \ldots , z_m$)

Answer (score 1):

L'hopital's (sp?) rule applied to
$\lim_{x \to 1} \dfrac{x^n-1}{x-1}$.